# Reading all lines from file asynchronously and safely

Tags: c#, io, .net-3.5

I'm trying to read from a file asynchronously, and safely (minimum level of permissions sought). I'm using .NET 3.5 and cannot find a good example for this (all uses async and await).

```
 public string GetLines()
    {
        var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] allText;
        using (FileStream stream =File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            allText = new byte[stream.Length];
            //something like this, but does not compile in .net 3.5
            stream.ReadAsync(allText, 0, (int) allText.Length);
        }
        return encoding.GetString(allText);
    }
```

Question is, how do I do this asynchronously in .net 3.5, wait till the operation is finished and send back all lines to the caller?

The caller can wait till the operation is complete, but the read has to happen in a background thread.

The caller is a UI thread, and I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: You want to do it asynchronously, but wait till the operation is finished?

Comment: You have to make the call to GetLines async. You don't make the change here.

Comment: Yes, taking into consideration that an UI is the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options, but the simplest would be to have this method accept a callback, and then call it when it has computed the given value.  The caller than needs to pass in the callback method to process the results rather than blocking on the method call:

```
public static void GetLines(Action<string> callback)
{
    var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] allText;
    FileStream stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open);
    allText = new byte[stream.Length];
    //something like this, but does not compile in .net 3.5
    stream.ReadAsync(allText, 0, (int)allText.Length);
    stream.BeginRead(allText, 0, allText.Length, result =>
    {
        callback(encoding.GetString(allText));
        stream.Dispose();
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait until the operation is complete, why do you need to do it asynchronously?

```
return File.ReadAllText(_path, new UnicodeEncoding());
```

Would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
GetLines(string path, ()=>
{
    // here your code...
});

public void GetLines(string _path, Action<string> callback)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    new Action(() =>
    {
        var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] allText;
        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            allText = new byte[stream.Length];
            //something like this, but does not compile in .net 3.5
            stream.Read(allText, 0, (int)allText.Length);
        }
        result = encoding.GetString(allText);
    }).BeginInvoke(x => callback(result), null);
}
```